# Why won't my CSS3 SVG Object animation go all the way across the screen?

Tags: css, svg

What's wrong with my CSS3 newbie animation? It won't go all the way across the screen even when I set it to **from** 0px, **to** 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/VCUgrad08/38grd6co/

Unfortunately the image won't show up but you can see the fallback text moving to get the gist of what's wrong.

```
<object id="pandaMove" data="http://svgshare.com/i/gY.svg" type="image/svg+xml">This is an image</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to {transform: translateX(100%);}` in the keyframe rules makes the svg container move by 100% of *it's own width*, not that of the parent element...

If you know the width of the svg element, you can use this type of rule (in my example the width would be 320px):

```
@keyframes pandaRight   {
  from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: calc(100% - 320px);}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7t6gcfr0/

Comment: OHHH that makes sense! *Homer Simpson Doh!*

This is the SVG code viewbox for the real image I need help with.

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 244 183" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

Comment: Update: Thank you so much Johannes! I applied you css3 to my code for my site and it works now! I have to wrap my head around the CSS calc function you did. Really cool!

Comment: Why is my SVG jumping when the site loads? http://sistersovercoming.org